# compile 'com.batch.android:batch-sdk:1.5+' error at this line in gradle?

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, sdk

please help me to solve  bug with Batch error
this error appears after run 
and  i make Sync but nothing happened

```
dependencies {
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
               androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
                })
                compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
                testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
                compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23'
                compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
                compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
                compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
                compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0'
                compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.0.0'
                 compile 'com.batch.android:batch-sdk:1.5+'
                 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
             }
```

[image]

```
import com.batch.android.Batch;
import com.batch.android.Config;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Batch;
```

Answer (score 0):

This lib is available only at `http://maven.batch.com/release` maven repository, so check out, whether your configuration points to this repository too< like so:

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven {
        url "http://maven.batch.com/release"
    }
}
```